# Как задать условие if?

Tags: python, php, if, условия

Извиняюсь за такой вопрос. Буду рад помощи и пойду спать...
Приведу пример.

Есть 5 продавцов орехов.

Количество орехов у продавцов:

```
Первый: 1000
Второй: 85000
Третий: 56000
Четвертый: 31000
Пятый: 16000
```

Продавцы готовы продавать свои орехи **за одну сделку** от и до такого количества:

```
Первый: от 500 до 1000
Второй: от 5000 до 85000
Третий: от 3000 до 56000
Четвертый: от 10000 до 31000
Пятый: от 4000 до 16000
```

То есть у нас есть такие условия для каждого продавца:

```
Первый: min = 500; max = 1000
Второй: min = 5000; max = 85000
Третий: min = 3000; max = 56000
Четвертый: min = 10000; max = 31000
Пятый: min = 4000; max = 16000
```

Теперь нужно вывести только тех продавцов, которые готовы продать 5000 или больше орехов.

Соответственно, получается условие:

```
Если min >= 5000: Вывести 'Номер продавца'
```

Что даст нам такой вывод:

```
Второй
```

Всё верно. НО. Третий и пятый продавцы тоже могут продать 5000 орехов или больше. Просто в из их объявлений в переменную min попадает другое количество, которое не соответствует условию. Так вот вопрос: как задать условие при котором выведутся все продавцы, у которых можно купить 5000 или больше орехов? То есть вот так:

```
Второй
Третий
Пятый
```

Comment: `if min <= 5000 <= max:`

Comment: не сработало( получился такой запрос в mysql  ... AND `limit_min` <= 5000 AND 5000 <= `limit_max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужно комплексное условие с использованием `and`:

```
seller = [
  [500, 1000],
  [5000, 85000],
  [3000, 56000],
  [10000, 31000],
  [4000, 16000]
]

for i, [min, max] in enumerate(seller):
  if (min <= 5000 and max >= 5000):
    print(f'{i+1} продавец:', min, max)
```

Вывод:

```
2 продавец: 5000 85000
3 продавец: 3000 56000
5 продавец: 4000 16000
```

Comment: Да, работает!) Спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Можно условие проще записать: `min <= 5000 <= max`

Comment: можно, но как я понял речь про `mysql` он такого не поймет

Comment: да нет, я всё понял ещё с комментария от splash58, там просто в другом проблема была, как оказалось. Но ответ всё равно верный

Comment: про `не поймет` я имел в виду мускул)) для этих целей там `between`